# Is the weighted average interest rate (aka WACC) strictly less than or equal to the combined value of the interest on those investment kept seperate?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, exponentiation, finance, programming

When combining multiple loans with separate interest rates into one interest rate, is it possible to reason about if the resulting interest rate will always be less than that of the combined investments?

To elaborate with equations:

Say we have an investment, with value $V_1$ and interest rate $R_1$, and another with $V_2$ $R_2$.

The value of the investment using the weighted average interest rate would be:

$$ (V_1 + V_2)((V_1 R_1 + V_2 R_2) / (V_1 + V_2)) ^ T$$

Where T is the time periods passed.

The actual value of these investments kept separate would be:

$$ V_1 R_1 ^ T + V_2 R_2^T$$

2 Questions about this:

1. Does there exist some perfect interest rate such that

$ V_1 R_1 ^ T + V_2 R_2^T = (V_1 + V_2)R_?^T$

that perfectly combines the two interest rates into one rate? My gut intuition is that this is impossible, but I have struggled to prove why.

2. Given #1 is impossible, can I reason that the weighted average interest rate is always going to be less than or equal to the true interest rate of the investments?

I've convinced myself that taken out to $T = infinity$ the true interest rates $ V_1 R_1 ^ T + V_2 R_2^T$ will outpace the weighted average, given $V_1 \ne V_2$, since the larger of $V_1$ or $V_2$ will outpace the weighted average rate, which must be somewhere between $V_1$ and $V_2$.

The question is though, is this true from T=1 onward, or is there some set of values for which the weighted sum is larger than the true investment value in the short term?

I've run a few examples with plugging in numbers, but I haven't been able to find any such values. I'm also not really sure how to approach proving or disproving this.

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated! For some context, I'm a developer looking at learning about the Aave smart contract system, and they use the weighted sum interest approximation inside of their contracts. I'm curious what effect this has on the overall system, and if there are any problems that could be caused by the weighted average interest rate being lower than the true interest rate loans were supposed to accrue.

Edit:

Here is an example:

I have one loan for \$1000 and is at a 10% interest rate. I have another loan for \$500 at a 20% interest rate. Both loans will be combined into one loan for $1500 with the following interest rate:

$$(1000 * 1.1 + 500 * 1.2) / (1000 + 500)$$

or $$(1100 + 600) / 1500 = 1.13333333333$$

So I will pay 13.3% interest on my loan. But this is not exactly what I would have paid if I kept the 2 loans separate.

In 2 years, the value of the weighted sum of rates would be:

$$1500 * 1.13333^2 = $1926.66$$

However if kept seperate, these loans would yield:

$$1000 * 1.1 ^ 2 + 500 * 1.2^2 = $1930$$

I've run lots of numerical examples, but in all of them I've seen that the weighted average interest rate ends up lower than the actual rate on the investments. My question is, can this be proved true or false?

Running algebra I quickly run into complexity of binomial expansions and cant seem to make much progress.

Also, I've come to know this method is also referred to as the weighted average cost of capital.

Comment: The average return   per period is 
$ \overline R=\sqrt[T]{\frac{V_1 (1+R_1) ^ T + V_2 (1+R_2)^T}{V_1+V_2} }-1. \quad$ $R_i$ are the return rates.

Comment: Yes, that equation can find an interest rate $R$ that intersects with the two interest points at a particular point in time T, but for all other values of T it wont be accurate. For example you could plug in T=25 years into that equation and find some interest rate that would match the original 2 at the 25 year point, but it will not match at either 24 or 26 years.

Comment: It is hard to follow for me. Post a numercal example  at 1the question field.

Comment: Updated with an example and some more information, thanks for taking the time to have a look so far!

Comment: Not a proof, but playing with graphs seems to confirm that the weighted average rate gives better return only for $0<T<1$: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4kxa6c8dpr

Comment: "but it will not match at either 24 or 26 years." Why is that a problem? You only care about the actualized values of the cashflows matching in the end. If you want more, you'll need a time-dependent interest rate. One rate will not do.

Comment: @BruceDarcy I've written an answer. I hope it clarifies some doubts. Feel free to ask, if something is still unclear.

Comment: @DavidK Thats very interesting. Seems to confirm the behavior I've observed even more.

Comment: @Raskolnikov right, I believe I see now why the weighted average must vary with time. For the system I'm looking at, its a smart contract that is compounding the interest continually, and doesn't really have a specific target time period. I am curious if the weighted average interest rate is always less than the actual combined returns on investments, because if the weighted average interest rate or WACC is every greater than the weighted average interest rate for some $T>1$, because if so, it would cause the contract to mispredict the earnings and essentially delete money from some people.

Comment: @callculus42, Thanks! I think I understand now the true average rate must vary with T.

Comment: @BruceDarcy You're welcome. If all is clear now, it would be nice if you marked my answer as accepted.

Comment: @callculus42 Hey sorry, I'm still unclear on the second part of my question, and really the one important on reasoning about the security of the smart contract, which is, is the WACC/weighted average of interest rates strictly less than or equal to the actual combined interest rates for $T>1, R_1,R_2 > 1$ (or 0 in your function form) $ V_1, V_2 > 0$. I appreciate your work helping me so far, but I want to keep this open in hope of getting some insight on that! If you haven't yet, the graphing on the problem by DavidK is a good visual aid to what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I I've written in the comments the average interest/return rate is $$\overline R=\sqrt[T]{\frac{V_1 (1+R_1) ^ T + V_2 (1+R_2)^T}{V_1+V_2} }-1$$,

where $R_i$ are the corresponding interest rates of the investments.

*Numerical example*

With $R_1=0.1, R_2=0.2, V_1=1000, V_2=500$ and $T=3$ the average return rate is

$$\overline R= \sqrt[\Large 3 ]{\frac{1000\cdot 1.1 ^ 3 + 500 \cdot 1.2^3}{1500} }-1=0.13530989...$$

See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%28%5Cfrac%7B1000%5Ccdot%20%281.1%29%5E3%20%2B%20500%20%281.2%29%5E3%7D%7B1500%7D%29%5E%281%2F3%29-1%29*2%2F2) for the computed result.

The two investments have an value at $T=3$ of $1000\cdot 1.1^3+500\cdot 1.2^3=2195$

Let's see if we can calculate the value of the two investments at $T=3$ with this average interest rate: $1500\cdot 1.13530989^3=2195$.  See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1500*1.135309891856%5E3) again for the computed result.

*General remarks*

The average interest rate is changing with $T$. The minimum of $\overline R$ is when $T=1$: $\frac{V_1 (1+R_1) + V_2 (1+R_2)}{V_1+V_2}-1=1+\frac{V_1R_1+V_2R_2}{V_1+V_2}-1=\frac{V_1R_1+V_2R_2}{V_1+V_2}=0.1333...$

In this case $R_2>R_1$. The more periods have past, the faster $V_2 $ grows in comparison to $V_1$. If we let T go to infinity we obtain $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \overline R=R_2=0.2$, the upper bound.

*continued*

That the average return increases when T increases can be seen if we look at the **power mean inequality** which is

$$\sqrt[q]{\sum_{i=1}^nw_ix_i^q}  \geq \sqrt[p]{\sum_{i=1}^nw_ix_i^p} \quad \forall \ \ p <q$$

In the numerical example we have $n=2, w_1=\frac{1000}{1500}=\frac23, w_2=\frac{500}{1500}=\frac13, x_1=1.1, x_2=1.2, p=1, q=3$.

$$\sqrt[\Large 3 ]{\frac{1000\cdot 1.1 ^ 3 + 500 \cdot 1.2^3}{1500} } \geq \sqrt[\Large 1 ]{\frac{1000\cdot 1.1 ^ 1 + 500 \cdot 1.2^1}{1500} } $$

$$\sqrt[\Large 3 ]{\frac{1000\cdot 1.1 ^ 3 + 500 \cdot 1.2^3}{1500} } \geq \frac{1100 + 600}{1500}$$

$1.13530989>1.133333$

With the power mean equality we can conclude as well, that the average interest rate is not constant, if $T$ changes.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140412/discussion-on-answer-by-callculus42-is-the-weighted-average-interest-rate-aka-w).